# C++ : Find the degree of a directed graph given the following text input

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

I am trying to find the degree of a rather large graph (for graph coloring) represented in a .txt file as such:

```
# Directed graph (each unordered pair of nodes is saved once): roadNet-PA.txt 
# Pennsylvania road network
# Nodes: 1088092 Edges: 3083796
# FromNodeId    ToNodeId
0   1
0   6309
0   6353
1   0
6353    0
6353    6354
6353    6364
6353    6386
6309    0
6309    6310
6309    6344
2   3
2   4
2   7
.   .
.   .
.   .
Etc.
```

Each row represents an edge connecting the first node to the second. 
What would be a good way to determine the degree of each vertex given this information? An answer wouldn't have to be in C++, pseudocode is sufficient :)

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider revising your question to make sure that you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that people are able to help you. Make sure to include *your own* attempt at the problem, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count how many times each number (node) appears.

```
void update_degree(std::map<int, int> &degree, int node) {
    if (degree.find(node) == degree.end()) {
        degree[node] = 1;
    } else {
        degree[node]++;
    }
}

std::map<int, int> get_degree(std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > edges) {
    std::map<int, int> degree;
    for (std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >::iterator it = edges.begin(); it != edges.end(); it++) {
        update_degree(degree, it->first);
        update_degree(degree, it->second);
    }
    return degree;
}
```